# How can I instantiate a new SystemError object in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, runtime-error, system-error

Looking at Node's [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_class_systemerror), `SystemError` extends the `Error` class. However, if you attempt to use `SystemError` directly, Node will throw a `ReferenceError` saying that `SystemError` is undefined.

Clearly, according to the docs, it is possible to encounter an instance of `SystemError`, but it seems impossible to recreate such an error in the usual way (e.g. `throw new SystemError(args)`).

I would like to test some code which is designed to interact with the specified `SystemError` API as detailed in the docs, but I have no idea how to recreate a `SystemError`. Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that you would need to import it with `require('errors')` or so, unlike the other errors it's not global. But I guess you *shouldn't* create `SystemError`s yourself anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that node.js doesn't put `SystemError` available in order to avoid anyone *(npm packages)* to use it. So a `SystemError` is really a `SystemError` and not something else.

If you want to test it, generate the error : Try to read a file that doesn't exist for example.

An other soluce would be to recreate a lookalike error because you know every property of it. But it's a workaround actually.

https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_class_systemerror

In the Github https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped I couldn't find any `interface` declaration of `SystemError`.

Except custom implementations made by `node-fetch`, `voximplant-websdk` and `alexa-sdk`.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/search?q=systemError&unscoped_q=systemError